# Struts application.properties file is not supporting accented characters

Tags: java, struts-1, resourcebundle

In struts application.properties we have key and value pairs. We use this file to display static text on html/jsp pages in browser.

But when I entered German characters from : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_script_charset

entered this text : αβγδεζηθ (Greek Symbols)

at some button in html page, it shows some different characters:

[image]

**Note :** i have used file encoding as UTF-8 in this case, and then compile the code.

What should i do to support these characters also. Please give some links so that it would be helpful.

Thanks....

Comment: I have also used <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />. but nothing gets changed they are still showing the above characters as defined the attached image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some characters cannot be stored AS IS on the properties file, it will have to entered using Unicode escape characters:

The default encoding for property files is `ISO-8859-1` also known as `Latin-1` characters. All non-Latin-1 characters must then be entered using Unicode escape characters.

Example, consider the following example using a french sentence:

```
#property file example:
sentence.french=Son père est allé à l'hôtel.
```

There are certain accents that are not part of the Latin-1 character set. Therefore, escaping it to its Unicode escape characters, we get:

```
#property file example:
sentence.french=Son p\u00e8re est all\u00e9 \u00e0 h\u00f4tel.
```

- [Source](http://archi.cetis.ac.uk/developer/translate-archi.html).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Is there any way to save the application.properties file in UTF-8 format. 
I am planning to use the below to try and read the application.properties file in utf-8 format. However, every time when i save this properties file with utf8 charectors, it just saved in ISO8859 format.
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");

Comment: Yes, use the [native2ascii](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/native2ascii.html) tool, which comes with the JDK, to convert a UTF-8 properties file to Unicode. See [example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-convert-chinese-character-to-unicode-with-native2ascii/).

Comment: But i think using native2ascii tool is not a good solution. Because we need to have greek or other languages characters, then we can use native2ascii if we don't have those character list, then its not useful.

Comment: One more thing to ask, i have created sample project Netbeans IDE with struts1.3.8. In application.properties i have defined the greek characters, when this application is launched in browser. it is displaying UTF-8 characters perfectly in greek language. then what can be the difference b/w these two.

Comment: I think, Netbeans IDE automatically calls native2ascii tool to convert to utf8 characters. When i am saving the properties file. the the greek characters are getting converted to unicode escape characters which @Buhake Sindi has told.