# How to store resource file in struts in UTF-8 format

Tags: java, utf-8, struts-1, properties-file, struts-config

Is there any way to store resource file(.properties) in struts 1.x in UTF-8 format. Whenever i save the file it is saved in ISO-8859 format.

Also, can i create a text file in resources folder of struts directory which will act as properties file (so that the text file can be saved in UTF-8 format), and read that file in  my application to show the static text of Greek, Russian or any language.

I have read the following and try to come up with the solution but it hasn't work :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/863854/3493471

Using this my code looks like this :

```
import java.util.Properties;
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

public class PropertiesListener {

        private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(PropertiesListener.class);

        protected  static Properties readProperties(String name){
                Properties prop = new Properties();
                InputStream inputStream = null;
                try {
                        //inputStream = new FileInputStream(name);
                        inputStream =  EditMailboxAction.class.getResourceAsStream(name);
                        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
                        log.debug("Length :: "+reader.ready());
                        try {
                                prop.load(reader);
                            } catch(Exception ex){
                                 log.debug("1111111111111111111111111");
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                             }finally {
                                reader.close();
                             }
                }catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
                         log.debug("22222222222222222222");
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                  }catch(Exception ex){
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                         finally {
                  }

                return prop;
        }
}
```

I have called this above function to read the file using :

```
Properties properties = PropertiesListener.readProperties("myProperties.properties");
```

But it doesn't make it helpful.

As myProperties.properties isn't storing UTF-8 Charectors, I don't understand how

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
```

will help in reading UTF-8 charectors.

Comment: "But it doesn't make it helpful" doesn't describe what you're seeing. You talk about "Whenever I save the file" - how are you saving the file? In an editor? With a Java tool?

Comment: My application runs in Linux, however to be safe , i ftp the myProperties.properties file to windows, open it in notepad++ and type the utf8 characters and save the file in Encoding UTF-8. Then i ftp the file to linux. Unfortunately when I open the file using vim in linux or even when i ftp it back to windows and again open in notepad++ it shows the output as gibberish characters. (Note: i have already changed putty settings to use utf-8)

Comment: That sounds like it's just a matter of using the incorrect mode in FTP. You probably want to use FTP in binary mode. Fundamentally though, if you can't transfer and edit a file appropriately, this has nothing to do with Java.

Comment: Its ok, now the application.properties file is displaying UTF8 charectors. But when it is used with struts-bean property it shows garbage charectors :
<console:label><bean:message key="com.console.searchButton"/></console:label>
For more information see this Question : http://stackoverflow.com/q/23650255/3493471